# JavaFX: Start and Pause Button not functioning correctly

Tags: animation, javafx

So I am trying to create a functioning Start and Pause Button. I have the following code so far:

```
    import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
    import javafx.animation.Timeline;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Group;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.util.Duration;

    public class pauseHelp extends Application{

private int xSpeed = 2;

public static void main(String[] args){
    Application.launch(args);
}
public void start(Stage first){
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene field = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
    field.setFill(Color.GREY);

    Circle ball = new Circle(20);
    ball.setFill(Color.RED);
    ball.setCenterX(field.getHeight()/2);
    ball.setCenterY(field.getWidth()/2);

    Button btnStart=new Button("Start"), btnPause = new Button("Pause");
    btnPause.setLayoutX(50);

    root.getChildren().addAll(ball,btnStart,btnPause);

    first.setScene(field);
    first.show();
    pauseGame(btnPause,ball);
    startGame(btnStart,ball);
}

private void begin(Circle ball, boolean active){
    KeyFrame k = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), e ->{
        moveBall(ball,active);
    });
    Timeline t = new Timeline(k);
    t.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    t.play();
}

private void moveBall(Circle ball, boolean active){
    if(active==true){
    ball.setCenterX(ball.getCenterX()+xSpeed);
    if(ball.getCenterX()>=500||ball.getCenterX()<=0){
        xSpeed=-xSpeed;
    }}
}

private void startGame(Button start, Circle ball){
    start.setOnAction(e->{
        begin(ball,true);
    });
}

private void pauseGame(Button pause, Circle ball){
    pause.setOnAction(e->{
        begin(ball,false);
    });
}}
```

The problem that I constantly get is that I cannot activate the Pause button, meaning when I click on it nothing happens.
Another problem that I am having with this code, is that each time one clicks on the Start Button the ball accelerates(I figured out that it has to do with the KeyFrame Duration, but cannot figure out how to change it).

I tried to use the Timeline-functions like `pause()`, but they also did not change anything.

Comment: Just create one timeline, instead of creating a new one every time you call `begin(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create multiple TimeLine when you are calling `start()`. Instead create just one timeline, use the buttons `start` and `pause` to play and pause it respectively.

Define the TimeLine as an instance variable so that it can be accessed everywhere. Initialize it inside the `start()`.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class PauseHelp extends Application{
    private Timeline t;
    private int xSpeed = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Application.launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage first){
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene field = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        field.setFill(Color.GREY);

        Circle ball = new Circle(20);
        ball.setFill(Color.RED);
        ball.setCenterX(field.getHeight()/2);
        ball.setCenterY(field.getWidth()/2);

        Button btnStart=new Button("Start"), btnPause = new Button("Pause");
        btnPause.setLayoutX(50);

        root.getChildren().addAll(ball,btnStart,btnPause);

        first.setScene(field);
        first.show();
        pauseGame(btnPause,ball);
        startGame(btnStart,ball);
        KeyFrame k = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), e ->{
            moveBall(ball);
        });
        t = new Timeline(k);
        t.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    }

    private void moveBall(Circle ball){
        ball.setCenterX(ball.getCenterX()+xSpeed);
        if(ball.getCenterX()>=500||ball.getCenterX()<=0){
            xSpeed=-xSpeed;
        }
    }

    private void startGame(Button start, Circle ball){
        start.setOnAction(e->{
            t.play();
        });
    }

    private void pauseGame(Button pause, Circle ball){
        pause.setOnAction(e->{
           t.pause();
        });
    }
}
```

You may also want to remove the methods `startGame()` and `pauseGame()` altogether and place these lines inside the `start()`

```
btnStart.setOnAction(e-> {
    t.play();
});

btnPause.setOnAction(e->{
    t.pause();
});
```